# jqxgrid handlekeyboardnavigation event in cell editing and clicking tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, jqxgrid

jqxgrid handlekeyboardnavigation event in cell editing and clicking tab
moves to next editable cell..But it should goes to next column cell..

Try in below fiddle

Start editing the `Last Name` column and press `Tab`. It will enter in `Ship Date` editor, but the `Product` cell got the `jqx-grid-cell-selected class`.
Is there any workaround from preventing it to happen? Any way to make grid navigation only avaliable in editable columns?
Thanks in advance!

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8691jjo2/)

Comment: Hi @john would like to check http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/cellediting.htm

Comment: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/cellediting.htm

Comment: those links doesn't answer to my scenario. That is from editable field(cell) to non-editable field(cell), if you are tabbing it moves to some other editable field(cell) in the grid instead of next column..

Comment: You may check it now my answer below fixed now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make column of PRODUCT editable.

```
{
    text: 'Product',
    datafield: 'productname',
    width: 177,
    //editable: false,
    cellbeginedit: beginedit,
    cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waqas61/7jb1dn4c/

Comment: Tabbing from `Last Name` goes to `Ship Date` column instead of going to `Product` column

Comment: Please read the question clearly. You made the `product` field as editable and showing in the fiddle. My question is how to tab to a `non-editable` field ? I want `product` field to be in `non-editable` field.